# Gap between twitter bootstrap navbar and content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am trying to get rid of the space behind twitter bootstrap's navbar for both large and small screens.

After reading on some resources I found this solution where i place my css between  bootstrap and responsive bootsrtap

```
 <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        body { padding-top: 0px; }
    }
    body { padding-top: 40px; }

</style>
<link href="/static/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This takes care of the space behind the navbar  when the browser screen is large but when the browser is reduces there is a gap between navbar and content. I thought `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {body { padding-top:0px; }}` was supposed to solve that problem.
What am i doing wrong please

Comment: I am having the same problem. However, unlike your CSS above, I placed my CSS with the media query after the `<link />` to the Bootstrap responsive CSS file. However, this does not seem to solve the problem. I hope someone else has figured this out--I can't find anything tracing the styles that would seem to result in this behavior.

Comment: See below; I've discovered what's causing the gap.

Answer (score 1):

The positioning is wrong.

Put the `@media` after so it will overwrite the 40px to 0, and not the opposite.

```
body { padding-top: 40px; }
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body { padding-top: 0px; }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I tried placing this CSS between the `<link />`s to the bootstrap default and responsive CSS stylesheets. I also tried putting just the `@media` query part after the inclusion of the Bootstrap responsive CSS stylesheet, but this didn't work either. Could you provide further details?

Answer (score 0):

I got to thinking about the problem and realized that if it wasn't the container or the header bar itself, maybe it's something I can't see? It turns out, it was. It's the hidden menus.

The following code in bootstrap-responsive.css is what's responsible for the gap between the header and the content:

```
.navbar-fixed-top { margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

It should be a simple matter of using the following media query (after the inclusion of bootstrap-responsive.css):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
}
```

Please note that I'm using v3.2.3 of Bootstrap.

**UPDATE:** I noticed that the gap re-appeared at wider browser widths. That's because the media query above is only for browser widths below 767px. I'd suggest changing the `max-width` property value of the media query to `979px`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

I had trouble with this same error and found this to work for me.